# does task scheduler close the program after the task is finished?

Tags: console-application, windows-task-scheduler

I have a task scheduled to run at 12 AM daily and the task runs a console application. Some how the console application doesn't close after the task is finished and I see it running in process explorer. Should the program automatically close after the task is finished?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What programming language are you using? What OS are you using? Does the program close if you run it manually instead via the task scheduler?

Comment: The console app is written in C#, OS is windows server 2008.Yes the program closes automatically when run manually. But it doesn't when run via task scheduler. Thank you.